# How to map response parameters of HTTP call with our predefined parameters in HTML code - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am in a situation like, I wrote the HTML code like below

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items" data-id="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

I am assuming the parameters of response of http call as below (In ItemComponent)

```
let response = [{
    id: 1, 
    name: 'Item 1'
}, {
    id: 2, 
    name: 'Item 2'
}]
```

But I am getting the response from **API** as below

```
response = [{
    item_id: 1, 
    item_name: 'Item 1'
}, {
    item_id: 2, 
    item_name: 'Item 2'
}]
```

Because of that response my HTML is not getting rendering. Is there any way to map original response parameters with our own predefined parameters.

**So that I need not to change bindings in HTML many times, if API people change the response parameters they are sending.**

**Note:** Angular 5

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to map the response of your API call. Something like this

```js
const response = [{
    item_id: 1, 
    item_name: 'Item 1'
}, {
    item_id: 2, 
    item_name: 'Item 2'
}];

const mappedResponse = response.map(item => ({
   id: item.item_id,
   name: item.item_name
}));

console.log(mappedResponse);
```